# JPA Join Column

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, database, jpa

I have 3 tables in database.

First one(categories) includes: id, category, isactive

Second one(menu) includes: parentid and childid.

Third one(items) includes: id, name and price.

First table has relationship with second. I want to do relationship between second and third now.

Second table has these values in a database:

- 7(id), book1(name), 120(price)
- 7(id), book2(name), 100(price)
- 8(id), car1(name), 1620(price)
- 8(id), car2(name), 520(price)
- 8(id), car3(name), 5520(price)
- 9(id), house1(name), 10000(price)
- 9(id), house2(name), 11000(price)
- 9(id), house3(name), 15000(price)

At the moment I have joined column childid to column id.

Menu.java

```
@EmbeddedId MenuId id;

@Column(name="PARENTID")
private Integer parentid;

@Column(name="CHILDID")
private Integer childid;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CHILDID",referencedColumnName="ID")

private Categories subcategories;

public Categories getSubcategories() {
    return this.subcategories;
}

public void setSubategories(Categories subcategories) {
    this.subcategories = subcategories;     
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="PARENTID", referencedColumnName="ID")
private Categories categories;

public Categories getCategories() {
    return this.categories;
}

public void setCategories(Categories categories) {
    this.categories = categories;
}

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CHILDID",referencedColumnName="ID")
private Items items;
public Items getItems() {
    return this.items;
}

public void setItems(Items items) {
    this.items = items;
}
```

Items.java has no modifications also as subcategories.java

I am using json object to print out my values:

```
jsonObject.put("parentid", menu.getParentid());
jsonObject.put("childid", menu.getChildid());
jsonObject.put("categories", menu.getCategories().getCategory());
jsonObject.put("subcategories", menu.getSubcategories().getCategory());
jsonObject.put("itemid", menu.getItems().getId());
jsonObject.put("product", menu.getItems().getProduct());
jsonObject.put("brand", menu.getItems().getBrand());
jsonObject.put("sum", menu.getItems().getSum());
```

It works, but it works not as I imagine on my project. It only prints same values:

- 7(id), book1(name), 120(price)
- 7(id), book1(name), 120(price)
- 8(id), car1(name), 1620(price)
- 8(id), car1(name), 1620(price)
- 8(id), car1(name), 1620(price)
- 9(id), house1(name), 10000(price)
- 9(id), house1(name), 10000(price)
- 9(id), house1(name), 10000(price)

and so on... But not this:

- 7(id), book1(name), 120(price)
- 7(id), book2(name), 100(price)
- 8(id), car1(name), 1620(price)
- 8(id), car2(name), 520(price)
- 8(id), car3(name), 5520(price)
- 9(id), house1(name), 10000(price)
- 9(id), house2(name), 11000(price)
- 9(id), house3(name), 15000(price)

So my question is should I use @OneToMany method? Or I do it in a wrong way?

Comment: to be honest i dont really understand what you are trying to achieve. can you provide some more details? perhaps include the classes in you question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was @Id annotation mapped to wrong PrimaryKey.

Answer (score 2):

Using `@OneToOne` is like extending a table (more columns) for some rows.

It seems like you are trying to set up a relation model for orders/bills and the positions of the orders/bills.

Normally (at least I would do so) you create a "parent"-table for the orders.

```
table order:
---------------
oder_id | customer | date | ...
--------+----------+------+-----
    1   |  cust_1  | ...  | ...
    2   |  cust_3  | ...  | ...
```

The positions of your order are in the "child"-table order_positions. A foreign key constraint (order_position.order_id to order.order_id) ensures the data integrity.

```
table order_position:
-----------------------
 id | oder_id | item     | price | ...
----+---------+----------+-------+-----
  1 |     1   |  book_1  | 100   | ...
  2 |     1   |  book_2  | 200   | ...
  3 |     2   |  car_1   | 2500  | ...
  4 |     2   |  car_2   | 234   | ...
```

To finally anser your question: Yes, in JPA you should use `@OneToMany`in your Oder-Entity and (if you want a bidirectional relationship) `ManyToOne`in your OrderPostion-Entity. Take a look at the examples in the [ObjectDB-Wiki](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/OneToMany)

Answer (score 1):

Assumming that one category have one menu. The correct anotation inside category is:

```
    @OneToOne
(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "menu", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Categories subcategories;
```

Inside your Categories you should have one menu object with this anotation:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Menu getMenu() {
    return this.menu;
}

public void setMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu= menu;
}
```

this is the correct way to do onetoone the way i understand it. if you need anything else do not hesitate to ask. The same applies for  category and item. you should have somethind like this inside your category:

```
 @OneToOne
    (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Items item;

And inside item you should have :
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Categories getCategories() {
        return this.category;
    }

    public void setCategories(Categories  category) {
        this.category= category;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not what I am looking for. Categories.java and Items.java are okey (Categories.java for sure). The problem is in Menu.java as it prints only same value(multiple times same id, name or sum) of each childid.

Comment: what is it that you really that you want to print? what you print probably depends on the query that make and not the relationship

Comment: Please look carefully in my post to see what is printed and what is expected to be printed.

Comment: i am currius, as you have a one to one relationship between category and menu what this line actually does: menu.getCategories().getCategory()
?

Comment: It gets categories from category table. menu.getSubcategories().getCategory()) get subcategories from category table.